# facebook - get users that liked an url?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have an iframe app on facebook.

There are several urls that users can like via like-button, eg. `http://my-domain.com/item/12`

Is there a way to get list of users (user ids) that likes the url?

Comment: well, if the url is on my domain, than it would be my business...

Comment: @Cek: Nonsense. Being able to correlate personal details of people who visit your website, without explicit permission, would be a horrible breach of privacy. Only a person's friends should be able to see what they "like" (or, however they have their privacy settings set up).

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal It would be a breash of privacy to list users that liked something in my fb app? The facebook like box shows faces of people that liked something, and like button is a *sharing* tool, is it not? Besides, check this out: https://graph.facebook.com/110516463305 and https://graph.facebook.com/110516463305/likes

Comment: @Cek: Looks like you just found the solution.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Coca Cola example works for all facebook opengraph objects, but I'm looking for a way to do the same with an url that's not an open graph object. Or... a way to make an open graph object from my url (many objects couse i have many url's). Tried og:type "article", but not shure what to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=http://my-domain.com/item/12&type=post&access_token=2227470867|2.PSGMtGYmflms8mb7zHtQsw__.3600.1304683200.0-531926632|rgg22I5Oj4as27JDMsPh9marq5U

It searches all public posts